# Runtime error 3705, operation is not allowed when object is open

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting error 3705 after adding the line

```
[MTSU_Data].[Tool no]=" CInt(WsInput.Range("J" & c).value) & ";"
```

The highlighted line where the error occurs is at

```
.ActiveConnection = conn
```

Full code

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Accdata As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Accfield As ADODB.Field
Dim wsQueryR As Worksheet, wsFinal As Worksheet

Set wsFinal = Worksheets("Final")
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Accdata = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\wongki7\Desktop\MTSU Db.accdb;"
conn.Open
'G:\BusUnits\MTSU\MTSU\Mold Tool Set Up\MTSU  Reports\Shift Reports\MTSU Db.accdb;"
' On Error GoTo CloseConnection

  For c = 2 To WsInput.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With Accdata
      .ActiveConnection = conn
      .Source = "SELECT * FROM [MTSU_Data] Where [MTSU_Data].[Date]>= #" _
            & Format(CDate(WsInput.Range("A2").value), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " # AND [MTSU_Data].[Date]<= #" _
            & Format(CDate(WsInput.Range("A3").value), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " # AND [MTSU_Data].[LT] = " _
            & CInt(WsInput.Range("M2").value) & " AND [MTSU_Data].[Tool no]=" _
            & CInt(WsInput.Range("J" & c).value) & ";"
      .LockType = adLockReadOnly
      '.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
      .Open
    End With
  Next
  Worksheets("Result").Select
  Sheets("Result").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Accdata
  Accdata.Close
  conn.Close
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks and have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not try to move the line

```
.ActiveConnection = conn
```

To outside the loop. Obviously fully qualifying it..

```
Accdata.ActiveConnection = conn
```

That looks to me that you are trying to make the connection for each iteration and I think it is only necessary once... maybe.

Comment: The error is now replaced with error 424 Object required. The highlighted line is  `.Source = "SELECT * FROM [MTSU_Data] Where [MTSU_Data].[Date]>= #" _
                    & Format(CDate(WsInput.Range("A2").value), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " # AND [MTSU_Data].[Date]<= #" _
                    & Format(CDate(WsInput.Range("A3").value), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " # AND [MTSU_Data].[LT] = " _
                    & CInt(WsInput.Range("M2").value) & " AND [MTSU_Data].[Tool no]=" _
                    & CInt(WsInput.Range("J" & c).value) & ";"`

Answer (score 0):

To best fit your code, Id try something like:

```
Sub SomeRoutine()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Accdata As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Accfield As ADODB.Field
Dim wsQueryR As Worksheet, wsFinal As Worksheet
Dim c As Long

Set wsFinal = Worksheets("Final")
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Accdata = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\wongki7\Desktop\MTSU Db.accdb;"
conn.Open
Accdata.ActiveConnection = conn
Accdata.LockType = adLockReadOnly

For c = 2 To WsInput.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Call Accdata.Open("SELECT * FROM BLah Blah")
    Sheets("Result").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Accdata
    Accdata.Close
Next
conn.Close
End Sub
```

You may be able to look at the way you build the SQL request to build a query to get the data in one go and and do a single paste to Excel with the CopyFromRecordset.... but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

A mistake I've made many times before. When assigning objects, you need to use Set. Change the line to

```
Set .ActiveConnection = conn
```

`.Source` and `.LockType` are scalar properties, so they don't need Set, but `.Activeconnection` does.